# Unable to save, with nested attribute and no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save input from a form, and for some reason it's unable to save - and no error appears in my console, nor when I call for error notifications on the form.

My form looks like this:

```
    <%= simple_form_for @line_item do |f| %> 
      <%= f.input :product_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @product.id } %>       
      <% @attribute_categories.each do |category| %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_item_attributes do |attributes_form| %>
          <%= attributes_form.association :product_attribute, collection: category.product_attributes, label: category.name %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.input :instruction %>

      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
```

and my create action looks like this:

```
  def create
    #product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    #@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.new(line_item_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url(product.store), notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        # format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

on my new action I have

```
  def new
    @product = Product.find_by(params[:product_id])
    @attribute_categories = @product.attribute_categories
    @line_item = LineItem.new
    @line_item.line_item_attributes.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and my `new.js.erb` renders a bootstrap modal that contains the form. The code for `new.js.erb` is:

```
$('body').append("<%= escape_javascript render('line_items/new_modal') %>");
$('#product-modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: First you should check if the params values are passed from your form to controller when you click on submit, So, did you try checking for params values in console after clicking on submit using debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `line_item_params` is allowing all the appropriate params for you to be able to save your object.

```
  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:all, :the, :params, :you, :are, :passing)
  end
```